# Ranking with LIKE keyword in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table like

```
╔═══════════════════╗
║     Title         ║
╠═══════════════════╣
║     Blogroll      ║
║     Bottom Menu   ║
║     Business      ║
║     Entertainment ║
║     extend        ║
╚═══════════════════╝
```

and my search criteria is like

```
WHERE title LIKE '%blogroller%'
```

obviously I will have no result here but can I find the count where the like clause ended, like here in this case its beyond 8 that made like clause fail??

Any hint would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this but only with lots of manual effort:

```
select title,
       (case when title like '%blogroller%' then 10
             when title like '%blogrolle%' then 9
             when title like '%blogroll%' then 8
             . . .
             else 0
        end) as MatchLen
from table t
order by MatchLen desc;
```

(Note:  in some versions of SQL Server, you might need a subquery to refer to `MatchLen`.)

Comment: I assume he's looking for a function that returns the number of matching characters.

Comment: this is the best I got so far

Comment: This is the best so far, but you should generalize it by adding each substring of your search term into a temp table or a delimited string, then run your case against that.  I can provide an example if you'd like.

Comment: @nikolifish . . . I would generalize it by creating a recursive CTE to pull out the patterns.  If you or the OP are interested, ask another question for a more general solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have ability to do it at once, so you have to try all options one by one, but you can significantly optimize this process - that's what SQL for.

First, convert pattern into all possible patterns, then just find MAX from all possible LIKEs. Not sure if SQL will be able to really optimize it now, but maybe in future it will.

```
-- test data

DECLARE @token NVARCHAR(100)
SET @token = 'Blogroller'

DECLARE @titles TABLE (Title NVARCHAR(100))

INSERT @titles VALUES
('Blogroll'),
('Bottom Menu'),
('Business'),
('Entertainment'),
('extend')

-- solution

DECLARE @patterns TABLE (part NVARCHAR(100) PRIMARY KEY, tokenLen int)

WHILE (LEN(@token) > 0) 
BEGIN
    INSERT @patterns VALUES (@token, LEN(@token))
    SET @token = SUBSTRING(@token, 1, LEN(@token) - 1)
END

SELECT MAX(patterns.tokenLen)
FROM @titles titles
INNER JOIN @patterns patterns ON titles.Title LIKE '%' + patterns.part + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind declaring a couple of variables and running a simple loop, you can do it this way:

```
declare @phrase as varchar(100) = 'blogroller'
declare @match_length as int = 0

while len(@phrase) > 0
begin
    if (select count(title) from titles where title like '%' + @phrase + '%') > 0
    begin
        set @match_length = len(@phrase)
        break
    end

    set @phrase = LEFT(@phrase, len(@phrase) - 1)
end

print @match_length
```

Comment: Its for search and with thousand of title referenced is while a good option??

Comment: Not necessarily - but if you have one search phrase only, it may not be bad. Your problem is not an easy one - may not be very easy to find a very good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some table with numbers (master..spt_values used in example) to break your search term into all possible shorter terms, and then join on it to find how many characters have matched:

setup:

```
CREATE TABLE Something (Title NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT Something (Title)
VALUES ('Blogroll')
,('Bottom Menu')
,('Business')
,('Entertainment')
,('extend')
```

query:

```
DECLARE @SearchTerm NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SearchTerm = 'Blogroller';

WITH CTE_SearchBroken AS 
(
    SELECT LEFT(@SearchTerm, number) BrokenTerm 
    FROM master..spt_values n
    WHERE n.type = 'P' AND n.number <= LEN(@SearchTerm)
)
, CTE_PreliminaryResults AS 
(
    SELECT *, LEN(BrokenTerm) AS BrokenAt 
    FROM Something s 
    LEFT JOIN CTE_SearchBroken b ON s.Title LIKE '%' + b.BrokenTerm + '%'
)
SELECT Title
    , MAX(BrokenAt) AS BrokenAt
    , CASE WHEN LEN(@SearchTerm) = MAX(BrokenAt) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Found
FROM CTE_PreliminaryResults
GROUP BY Title
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Gordon's answer, you can write a function that automatically loops through all the possibilities. Also similar to Lanorkin's answer; his might have better performance because it makes good use of inner join; you may want to do some tests there.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MatchLen(@needle AS varchar(max), @haystack AS varchar(max)) RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @len AS int = LEN(@needle)
    WHILE @len > 0 AND @haystack NOT LIKE '%' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT(@needle, @len), '[', '[[]'), '%', '[%]'), '_', '[_]') + '%'
        SET @len = @len - 1
    RETURN @len
END
```

Example:

```
SELECT dbo.MatchLen('blogroller', 'This blog has no blogroll, sir!')
```

returns 8.

Answer (score -1):

Please try:

```
select 
    *,
    LEN(Title) MatchLength
From YourTable
where 'Blogroller' like Title+'%'
```

OR

```
select 
    *,
    LEN(Title) MatchLength
From YourTable
where 'Blogroller' like '%'+Title+'%'
```

Comment: Not downvoting, but - he doesn't want LEN, he want to find which LEN in pattern *would* work

Comment: @Lanorkin I accept that, but do the above query return a wrong result?

Comment: He wants the number of matching characters. So if the title is `Big` there's one matching character(the first).

Comment: but what if I have 'roll' in where or even any words??

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes - if you try it with 'Menu' for example, but I really like your approach now, when started thinking about it